# setAttribute without name validation

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to add attribute to HTML element inside JS.
I'm using setAttribute, however I need to add attribute `[foo]` - which is invalid attribute name - in my case it's fine as later in processing anyway attribute is converted to valid value `foo`

The problem is that setAttribute is throwing error saying it's invalid name.

Is there any way to add attribute without name validation?

Code:

```
// el is HTMLInputElement

el.setAttribute("[foo]", "test");

// error - Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[foo]' is not a valid attribute name.
```

It's in Chrome v59

pen to reproduce it: https://codepen.io/kheim/pen/OgrZwj

Thanks!

Comment: please add your code here

Comment: It should not throw an error. Are you giving a value to your attribute ?

Comment: Are you using angularJs

Comment: This is interesting. As far as I can tell, according to [the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0), `[foo]` is actually a valid attribute name but no browser I have available to me wants to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `[]` while using `setAttribute`.

Your JS should instead be:

```
// el is HTMLInputElement

ele.setAttribute("foo", "test");
```

Comment: but I need to add brackets - it's required by my logic.

Comment: @user1038334 Changing your logic is the better option then, by far.

Comment: not possible, it's like adding dynamically attribute to be picked by angular (not actual case - but very similar)

Comment: Can you not make use of custom `data-*` attributes ? Browsers would render attributes with `[]` as invalid HTML.

Comment: Browser will never render it, before it's added to display attribute in strip from [].

Comment: Obviously the stripping is not happening before. You would not be getting the error otherwise. Meaning browser is reading it.